# Some unicode characters dont render on some devices

Tags: android, math, unicode, fonts

I am using a button with the text set to 10\u02E3. This should show 10 and (superscript x) (10⁷) , but on some devices, it does not. I tested this on Nokia X, it shows. On galaxy S2, I don't get the superscript at all, I just get the 10.

What should I do to render superscripts and subscripts on all devices? Is there any way to 'include' them in my app in case they are not already present?

Comment: hmmm... what about using `myText.setText(HTML.fromHTML("10<sup>x</sup>"));`?

Comment: Looks like a font issue, but then, Unicode Consortium recommends using different ways of creating superscript characters anyway. Can you bundle a font with your app?

Comment: yes, i can. What do I have to do after exporting the .ttf ?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to android not able to find a Font that supports the rendering of the glyph that you are trying to generate, the usual process is checking `/system/etc/system_fonts.xml` and if not found it tries to check in the `fallback_fonts.xml`

You can check the file [here](https://gist.github.com/ascendedguard/7355854)

It is tough to assume all devices carry these rendering capabilities, the best(tough) way to ensure that you are able to display the glyph is by overriding Android's default TextView with a custom component, and drawing the glyph the way you want.